# Webpack2 pug не вставляются картинки

Tags: html, frontend, webpack, jade, pug

При компиляции.pug выдает ошибку, что require не является функцией. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само подключение картинки в файле index.pug

```
body
    h1 Pug - node template engine
    #container.col
        if youAreUsingPug
            p You are amazing
        else
            p Get on it!
        img(src=require('./images.jpg'))
```

Конфиг обработки

```
module:{
    rules:[
        {
            test:/\.pug/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use:['html-loader','pug-html-loader']
            }),
        },
        {
            test:/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)/,
            use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
},
```

Пытался экранировать require, но ничего полезного так и не получилось.
Как подключать картинки?

Answer (score 0):

у меня так работает

просмотрите этот вопрос там более подробно описал
[Картинки не загружаются webpack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772879/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-webpack)

```
module.exports = function(){
  return{
    module:{
      rules:[
        {
          test:/\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options:{
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath :  'images/',
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```