# Картинки не загружаются webpack

Tags: изображения, webpack, path, pug

На devserer-e все работает правильно и картинки загружаются, но на продакшне картинки загружаются только на начальную страницу. В остальных страницах путь не совпадает. Или кратко, во всех страницах используется один путь. Например на главной ***images/3hpZZVr.png***, и так же на странице *site.ru/about* тот же путь ***images/3hpZZVr.png*** вместо ***../images/3hpZZVr.png*** этого.

вот собственно сам модуль:

```
module.exports = function(){
  return{
    module:{
      rules:[
        {
          test:/\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options:{
            name: '[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
            outputPath :  'images/',
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение 
Надо было перед именем тоже поставить слэш чтобы картинки грузились с главной страницы

```
module.exports = function(){
  return{
    module:{
      rules:[
        {
          test:/\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options:{
            name: '/images/[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
            outputPath :  '/images/',
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```